# Package android. support.v4.content does not exist

Tags: ionic-framework

I am getting this error please help
It error become when i convert ionic to apk in android studio.
I have tried a lot but cant solve still.

Comment: Thanks to all
Problem solved i have changed code in fileprovider file
Android .support. v4.content into  Androidx.core.content

Answer (score 0):

This was my problem too. this is caused because of Google servers is blocking you. follow these steps:

1. use a VPN (crucial)
2. run your CMD and navigate to project root (only CMD)
3. run `ionic cordova build android`

inform me of the result. Good Luck!